# Vector field on manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I've only seen a vector field $V$ on a manifold $M$ as a mapping $V:M\to TM$. Is it true that they can also be seen as a mapping $V:C^{\infty}\left(M\right)\to C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$? How would $V$ work in the second case?

Comment: Are you familiar with the interpretation of tangent vectors at a point $p$ as derivation at $p$?

Comment: The correct definition of a smooth vector field on a smooth manifold $ M $ is that it is a smooth map $ V: M \to TM $ such that $ V(p) \in T_{p} M $ for every $ p \in M $.

Comment: @knsam I have come across that definition before. I believe it is that if $v_p$ is a derivation at $p$ then $v_p:C^{\infty}\left(M\right)\to\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore You are correct actually. I will update my post.

Comment: Yes. We can definitely view a tangent vector $ v \in T_{p} M $ as a linear map $ D: {C^{\infty}}(M) \to \Bbb{R} $ such that $ D(f g) = D(f) g(p) + f(p) D(g) $ for every $ f,g \in {C^{\infty}}(M) $.

Comment: Yes, a vector field on $M$ can be seen as  a $\mathbb R $-linear map $V:C^{\infty}\left(M\right) \to C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$ satisfying  $V(fg)=V(f)g+fV(g)$ for all $f,g\in C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$.

Comment: user327878: Indeed, does my answer below help you? I can elaborate more, but I believe you are now in the good hands of @GeorgesE. :) Best,

Comment: @knsam: It seems that the OP is confused by the difference between a vector field and a tangent vector. The former is viewed as a derivation from $ {C^{\infty}}(M) $ to itself, while the latter is viewed as a derivation from $ {C^{\infty}}(M) $ to $ \Bbb{R} $.

Comment: Dear knsam: thanks but I'm just stating a result and your answer (which I have upvoted)  gives the reason for the statement, and is thus very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of things to point out here. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold.

- Every tangent vector at $p$ may be thought of as a *derivation at $p$*: indeed, if $v_p$ is a tangent vector at $p$ and $f: U \to \mathbf{R}$ is a smooth function in a neighbourhood $U \subseteq M$ of $p$, then, $v_p(f)$ can be thought of as the derivative of $f$ at $p$ in the direction of $v$. More precisely, for a curve $\gamma$ defined around $0$ (so that $\gamma(0) = p$) which represents the tangent vector $v_p$, one sets:

$$v_p(f) = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}(f \circ \gamma)}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}.$$

Firstly, this is well-defined: that is, the definition of $v_p$ is independent of the curve $\gamma$ that "represents" $v_p$. (This is "per definitionem", like everything is.)

The name comes from the fact that $v_p: C^\infty(U) \to \mathbf{R}$ satisfies the identity $$v_p(fg) = f(p) v_p(g) + g(p) v_p(f).$$

- Equipped with the above interpretation as derivation at a point $p$, we may view a *smooth* vector field $X$ as a derivation $\mathcal{L}_X: C^\infty(M) \to C^\infty(M)$ on the algebra $C^\infty(M)$ by setting $\mathcal{L}_X(f)(p) = X_p(f)$. (Check that this makes sense!)

See Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, a wonderful book on differential topology.

Comment: I second knsam excellent judgment of Lee's book.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is $X_p$ is the tangent vector we get after plugging $p$ into $V$? If so, isn't $X_p\left(f\right)$ a real number since we are evaluating the derivative at the point $p$?

Comment: I suppose I should have used $V$ as in OP, but yes, your interpretation is correct. Note that the smooth function $\mathcal{L}_X(f)$ is defined pointwise: at $p$, the real value it takes is $X_p(f)$.

Comment: Well if $X_p\left(f\right)$ is a real number, I don't quite see how $f$ is mapped to another function (isn't it mapped to that real number?). Could you elaborate a little more on this part?

Comment: @user327878: The image of $f$ under $\mathcal{L}_X$ is the function $p \mapsto X_p(f)$. Does this description clarify?

Comment: I think I see it now. So just to summarize, the actual definition of a vector field is a smooth map $V:M\to TM$, taking a point and returning a vector in the tangent space at $p$. However, if we first choose a smooth function $f$ then $V$ can be thought of as a map from $C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$ to $C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$, taking in $f$ and returning the function $X_{\left(\cdot\right)}\left(f\right)$. $X_{\left(\cdot\right)}\left(f\right)$ takes in a point $p$ on the manifold and finally returns a real number. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I think you have it right. :)

Comment: Thanks, very grateful for your help.