# About vector fields in manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

maybe this question is to basic, but I am a litle bit confused with the definition of vector field in a manifold. Following
this cuestion [Vector field on manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730074/vector-field-on-manifold), I know that
I can see a vector field as a derivative, and it can be expressed in the basis of the tangent space, i.e.
if $X$ is a vector field, then if we restrict to a neighborhood $U$ of the manifold
\begin{equation}
X=\sum _{i=1}^{n} f_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
\end{equation}
So, if I take a fonction $f$ smooth enough, we have that
\begin{equation}
X(f)=\sum _{i=1}^{n} f_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(f)
\end{equation}
Is this last statement correct?

Comment: Yeah. Your last statement is correct. Note that $
X_p=\sum _{i=1}^{n} f_i (p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\big|_p$ for all $p\in U$. So, $X_p(f)=\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\big|_p(f)$ for all $p\in U$. Recall the action of tangent vector on germ at $p$.